# Copy files from directory to SSH Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-system, ssh

The overall idea is:  I have an Android phone and I would like to copy the files in a folder from the phone (which is running an SSH server, that's how I connect to it) to a harddrive connected to my Raspberry Pi.

<sub>(I want to know, for sure, what files on my Android were copied to the Harddrive, which is why I have the filenames get a `_c` amended to them. (So `20190321.jpg` becomes `20190321_c.jpg` on my phone.) That should show me, without doubt, that I can delete the file on my Android since it was successfully copied to the Harddrive.)</sub>

I am decently familiar with Python, but this is the most "advanced" program I've made.  The SSH stuff was put together via trial/error and lots of SE/Google searching.

Any suggestions, from PEP8 conventions, to better workflow, are very much appreciated!  I tried to handle errors correctly, but am curious if the `quit()` in the exceptions is what I want to do, or if that's not how it should be handled. (Note the `ssh.close() // quit()` are repeated in both exceptions.)

I know some of my docstrings are rather obvious, but I keep reading it's best practice to include them, but any tips are appreciated there too.

The SublimeText linter doesn't show any PEP8 suggestions, so I think I'm doing good so far on that point, but of course defer to your wise judgement :)  Also, is there a "best practice" to the order my functions should be in?

A final note - this should copy the files, and **all** metadata/EXIF data, etc. so that I don't leave any parts out. AFAIK it does, just thought to mention here in case `sftp.get()` strips something out that I won't notice until later.

Edit: Ah, forgot to mention: you'll note that sometimes I do `directory + filename` and another I do `os.path.join(directory, filename)`...any big difference I  those or would it just be user preference?

```
import paramiko as pmko
import os
from PIL import Image
import re


def get_date_taken(path):
    """ 
    This will be implemented later and is currently
    just to test how to get EXIF data from photos.
    """ 
    return Image.open(path)._getexif()[36867]


def list_files(directory, filetype, ssh):
    """
    This will scan a directory for the filetype,
    which is passed as `.jpg`, or `.mp3`, etc. and return
    a list of those files.
    """
    print("Collecting filenames of all photos in", directory)
    distantFiles = list()
    filePath = '/storage/emulated/0/' + directory
    filePattern = '"*' + filetype + '"'
    rawcommand = 'find {path} -name {pattern}'
    command = rawcommand.format(path=filePath, pattern=filePattern)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
    filelist = stdout.read().splitlines()
    for afile in filelist:
        (head, filename) = os.path.split(afile)
        distantFiles.append(filename)
    return distantFiles


def connect_to_ssh_server(host_ip, port, username, password):
    """
    This will connect to an SSH Server and return the sftp and
    ssh objects
    """
    print("Starting connection to", host_ip)
    ssh = pmko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(pmko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        ssh.connect(host_ip, port=port, username=username,
                    password=password)
        sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
        print("Connected!")
        return sftp, ssh
    except pmko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError:
        print("No valid connections for", host_ip)
        ssh.close()
        quit()
    except TimeoutError:
        print("Connection attempt timed out when trying to connect to",
              host_ip)
        ssh.close()
        quit()


def fix_filenames(files, directory, rgx, replacement, sftp):
    for file in files:
        if type(file) != str:
            file = file.decode('utf-8')
        if file.endswith(".jpg_c"):
            print("Fixing", file)
            new_end = re.sub(rgx, replacement, file)
            print(directory + file, " will be in ", directory + new_end)
            sftp.rename(directory + file, directory + new_end)


def download_file(sftp, filename, origin, destination):
    sftp.get(origin + filename, destination + filename, callback=None)


def rename_file(sftp, filename, directory, suffix):
    """
    This will rename a file in a directory with the passed in suffix.
    """
    extention = filename.rsplit(".")[1]
    new_name = re.sub(r"\..*", suffix + extention, filename)
    print(filename, "will become", new_name)
    sftp.rename(directory + filename, os.path.join(directory, new_name))


def copy_all_files(lst, origin_directory, destination, ssh, sftp):
    """
    This copies files from a list, from an origin directory
    to the destination.
    """
    for _file in lst:
        if type(_file) != str:
            _file = _file.decode('utf-8')
        if not bool(re.search(r'\_c\.', _file)):
            try:
                download_file(sftp, _file, origin_directory, destination)
                rename_file(sftp, _file, origin_directory, "_c.")
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Could not find", origin_directory + _file)
                continue
            except OSError:
                print("OSError on", str(os.path.join(
                    origin_directory, _file)), "--------------<<")
                continue
        else:
            print(_file, "already copied")


def main():
    sftp, ssh = connect_to_ssh_server(
        "192.168.0.100", 2222, "testUsr", "supersecretpassword")
    android_path = "DCIM/camera/"
    # use `.*` to copy all filetypes
    files = list_files(android_path, ".*", ssh)
    origin_directory = '/storage/emulated/0/' + android_path
    copy_all_files(files, origin_directory, '/media/pi/My Passport/Galaxy S8/',
                   ssh, sftp)
    ssh.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is decent code, job well done!

I have a few nitpicks,

- PEP8 violations

  1. Functions and variables should be `snake_case`
  2. [Group your imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

  There are multiple tools out there that checks your code PEP8 violations
- When joining paths => us [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) or `os.path.join`

  Adding paths via string concatenations can be error prone, it is best to use `os.path.join(path1, path2)`

  For instance it will handle cases when you try to add `/a/b/` with `/c/d`

  You do this in a few places, but not all the time. Stay consistent!
- `extention = filename.rsplit(".")[1]`

  You can use `root, extentsion = os.path.splittext(filename)`
- You can catch multiple exceptions at once

  ```
  except (pmko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError, TimeoutError):
  ```
- Instead of printing what went wrong, try [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)

  Print statements are there for a short time, logs are forever
- `if not bool(re.search(r'\_c\.', _file)):`

  Here `bool` is superfluous when no match is found it will return `None`, which is Falsey

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and comments!  1) Looks like I mostly grouped imports, just need to move the `from x import y` to the end? 2) Yes! That's exactly what I was trying to figure out, because it's going to happen where I forget to add a trailing `/`, so the concat won't work. 3) Most excellent, because this also avoids any issue where I have a `.` in the filename (however rare, it's awesome I can truly split on the extension like that, great tip!), 4) Noted! 5) Thanks for that, I haven't come across logging, will check out!, 6) Noted! ...thanks again, these are excellent points :D

Comment: Also, just for the record, it's `os.path.splitext()`, not `...splittext()`, as I found after getting an `AttributeError`. ...which is odd. Perhaps a typo in Python library? Who knows!

Comment: That is easy to misspell ;). About the imports both PIL and paramiko are 3th party tools, and should be at the end. The PEP8 link has all the rules regarding imports

Comment: Sorry to ask another question - can you clarify the last point? Do I simply need to remove the `bool`? (I'm studying up on Falsey/True-y/bool, but maybe a quick explanation here would help quicker. No worries if not, your answer (especially the `logging` part) have already taught me tons and sent me down a few fun rabbit holes.. :D

Comment: @BruceWayne No problem! You can either simply remove the `bool` since `None` is Falsey or be explicit with `if re.search(...) is None`